# SQLPLUS dont create row

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sqlplus

I have unusual problem with SQLPLUS connected with OracleDB 10g. I have table with sequence and trigger to autoincrement id. I created script for inserting some data into that table. When I called it form SQLPLUS everything goes ok (without error), but that rows are not visible in object browser. When I call the same command from SQL command it show in table without any problems.

Any ideas?

Creating tables script:

```
-- Create table with drivers
   CREATE TABLE drivers (
       id NUMBER NOT NULL,
       name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
       forname VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
       plate_nr VARCHAR2(7) NOT NULL,
       engine NUMBER(2,1) DEFAULT 1.4 NULL CHECK(engine > 0), -- check allow only values that meets statement
       passanger_space NUMBER DEFAULT 3 NULL CHECK(passanger_space > 0),
       luggage_space NUMBER DEFAULT 150 NULL CHECK(luggage_space > 0),
       PRIMARY KEY (id) -- id is unique inside table and most important
   );

   CREATE SEQUENCE  drivers_seq; -- create sequence for table

   CREATE OR replace TRIGGER drivers_trg -- create trigger
   BEFORE INSERT ON drivers -- if user want to add row into table
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     SELECT drivers_seq.nextval INTO :NEW.id FROM dual; -- get next value (autoincrement)
   END;
   /
```

Insert data script:

```
   INSERT INTO drivers (name,forname,plate_nr,engine,passanger_space,luggage_space)
               SELECT 'Paweł','Jakubowski','ABC1234',1.4,3,150     FROM dual
   UNION ALL   SELECT 'Piotr','Dobrzański','ABC4321',1.8,2,NULL    FROM dual
   UNION ALL   SELECT 'Kamil','Nowak','77G0D77',2.2,15,500         FROM dual
   UNION ALL   SELECT 'Agnieszka','Kowalska','B3AU7Y6',1.4,3,175   FROM dual
   ;
```

Comment: You need to `commit` your insert.

Comment: Thanks! Work like a charm :)